# Make overlay fade in and fade out slower

Tags: javascript, html, css

courtesy N0ME on this site, I have been able to get the HTML, CSS, and Javascript below.

```
        <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTarget(event){
    target = (typeof window.event === "undefined")?event.target:window.event.srcElement;
    return target;
}

document.onclick = function(event){
    var target = getTarget(event);
    if(target.id == ""){
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
        var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        button.style.color="#000000";
    }

}


function toggleOverlay(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
    overlay.style.opacity = .7;
    if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        button.style.color="#000000";
    } else {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
        button.style.color="#ff0000";
    }
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">

div#overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #A9A9A9;
    position: fixed;
    width: 879px;
    height: 291px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#specialBox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 719px; 
    height: 215px;
    top: 88px;
    left: 80px;
    background: #FFF;
}
div#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:24px;
        border:none;
        color:#000
}
    .btn:hover{ 
    color:#F00; 
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .x {
        background-color:white;
        cursor:pointer;
        font:Arial;
        font-size:14px;
        color:red;
        z-index: 4;
        position: fixed;
        top: 92px;
        left: 766px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Start Overlay -->
<div id="overlay"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<div id="specialBox">
  <button class="x" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">X</button>
</div>
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<!-- Start Normal Page Content -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <button id="qualityButton" class="btn" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">HIGHEST QUALITY</button>
</div>
<!-- End Normal Page Content -->



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the buttons, the overlay appears and disappears in one quick flash. I would like it to take for example 500ms so that a fade in/fade out effect is created.

I've tried adding the following script without any luck:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".x").click(function(){
    $("p").toggleOverlay(500)
  });
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    $("p").toggleOverlay(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

Could anyone please guide me as to what I'm doing wrong and how I could solve the issue?

Thank you so much in advance.

James

Comment: You miss to get the jQuery library inside your `<head>` tag, like this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` - for your second script

Comment: @aldanux Unfortunately adding the line still does not have any effect...

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the `transition-duration` style to your button like this:

```
button .x{transition-duration:0.5s}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Tried this without any luck :(

Comment: That's because CSS3 transitions don't work if you modify the display property of an element. The display property doesn't support transitions and if you change the display property it will also break all other transitions on that element.

Comment: @LifeOnLars Thanks for your comment. Would you have any suggestion as to how I can solve the matter?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding delay(500) before toggleoverlay()

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".x").click(function(){
    $("p").delay(500).toggleOverlay();
  });
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    $("p").delay(500).toggleOverlay();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in fact using jquery, this is what you want:

```
function toggleOverlay(){  
$('#overlay, #specialBox').fadeToggle(500);
}
```

get rid of the extra jquery you added, and just replace your toggleOverlay function with the above.

http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer! It does partly work: If I click the quality button to make the overlay appear/disappear, the fade is perfect. However, clicking on the 'X' button or on the document to close the overlay continues to close it without any fade effect. Any clues to how I could fix that? Thanks!